# How to get column values corresponding to other columns minima in MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have some example data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"name": "cat", "var": "v1", "col1": 5, "col2": 7},
    {"name": "cat", "var": "v2", "col1": 4, "col2": 8},
    {"name": "dog", "var": "v1", "col1": 11, "col2": 15},
    {"name": "dog", "var": "v2", "col1": 12, "col2": 14},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("DATA\n", df)
```

```
DATA
   name var  col1  col2
0  cat  v1     5     7
1  cat  v2     4     8
2  dog  v1    11    15
3  dog  v2    12    14
```

I would like to get all values of `col2` where `col1` is minimum with each `name`, like the following:

```
name  col2
cat   8
dog   15
```

My idea was to first pivot the data to deduplicate the names:

```
df = df.pivot("name", "var", ["col1", "col2"])
print("\nPIVOT\n", df)
```

```
PIVOT
      col1     col2    
var    v1  v2   v1  v2
name                  
cat     5   4    7   8
dog    11  12   15  14
```

Then I could get the minimum indices, to know which `var` contains the minimum for `col1`:

(Side note: is there a way to select just all `var`s without listing each possiblity?)

```
dfMinIdx = df[[("col1", "v1"), ("col1", "v2")]].idxmin(axis=1)
print("\nMINIDX\n", dfMinIdx)
```

```
MINIDX
 name
cat    (col1, v2)
dog    (col1, v1)
dtype: object
```

Now I know that for `cat` `v2` should be selected and for `dog` it should pick `v1`.

But this is where I'm suck. How would I access the `col2` values from `dfMinIdx`?

This is how I built an adjusted indexing DataFrame, but not sure how to "apply" it to df:

```
dfOtherIndex = dfMinIdx.transform(lambda x: ("col2", x[1]))
```

---

An alternative question would be how do I access a MultiIndex (here "PIVOT") with a Series of tuples (here "MINIDX")? I just wanted to give the full context in case I'm on the wrong path.

Comment: What is your expected output? Actually not so clear from *get all values of col2 where col1 is minimum with each name.*

Comment: @SomeDude I added the expected output